# Visual Studio warning C4334 on assignment but not on initialization

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings

Why i got warning on this code:

```
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int64_t i64;
    i64 = 1 << i;
}
```

> warning C4334: '<<' : result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits (was 64-bit shift intended?)

but not on this:

```
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int64_t i64 = 1 << i;
}
```

? 
Tested on vs2013/2015.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same discrepancy with vs2012. I don't think that there is a good reason for it - hopefully the warning will be emitted in both cases in a newer version of Visual C++.

Answer (score 0):

MSVS 2015 Upd.2: Second case (on initialization) will trigger C4334 warning.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?