# VS compilation warning: result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, bit-shift

Visual Studio 2013 issues an annoying (and seemingly irrelevant) compilation warning on:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define PRECISION 16

uint64_t hi = 0;
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
{
    if (some_condition)
    {
        hi += 1 << (PRECISION - 1 - i);
    }
}
```

Here is the compilation warning:

```
warning C4334: '<<' :
result of 32-bit shift implicitly converted to 64 bits (was 64-bit shift intended?)
```

It seems to be resolved when changing `1 << (PRECISION - 1 - i)` to `1 << (PRECISION - 1)`.

So I've been trying to figure out what could possibly go wrong in `1 << (PRECISION - 1 - i)`.

Obviously, if `i >= PRECISION`, then the shift-left operation would yield undefined behavior.

However, the variable `i` does not exceed the value of `PRECISION - 1`.

Moreover, even if we assume that the compiler cannot infer this fact, I don't see what this compilation warning has to do with a potential undefined behavior due to the shift-left operand.

Perhaps it assumes that the unsigned value of `PRECISION - 1 - i` can be larger than 31.

But how exactly am I supposed to tell the compiler that it never does?

I found [one related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31558314/1382251), but there are no proper answers provided.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler [indeed suspects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke55d167.aspx) that 64-bit was meant:

> The result of 32-bit shift was implicitly converted to 64-bits, and the compiler suspects that a 64-bit shift was intended. To resolve this warning, either use 64-bit shift, or explicitly cast the shift result to 64-bit.

You may consider

```
hi += uint64_t(1) << (PRECISION - 1 - i);
```

Perhaps removing `i` suppresses the warning because the compiler treats expression as a constant.

Comment: The integer literal suffix `i64` is a Microsoft extension. It's better to use `ULL` or `ull` when portability matters.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune I see your point. But `ULL`might be longer than 64 bits, so it is not ideal either. I changed to `uint64_t(1)`.

Comment: if you want portability use std::size_t(1)

Answer (score 6):

The compiler is complaining because you store the result in a 64 bit variable so it assumes you actually wanted to do a 64 bit shift instead of a 32 bit shift.  You can fix that by using

```
hi += 1ULL << (PRECISION - 1 - i);
```

To force it to be a 64 bit shift.

It would also not complain if `hi` was a `unint32_t`.

Comment: So why is the warning cleared when I change `PRECISION - 1 - i` to `PRECISION - 1` (while still storing the result in a 64 bit variable)???

Comment: @barakmanos My guess is the same as Alex's. `1 << PRECISION - 1` is a compile time constant so it is probably optimized away to `hi += constant`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Storage of the result is unrelated to this warning and if `hi` is 32-bit, the original error will persist. This warning is specific to the shift operation itself (possibly VS-specific behavior)